# Doubts about the criterion used to close one of my questions as off-topic

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic, broken-windows

My question https://stackoverflow.com/q/11636793/100297 was closed as being "off topic".

How can my question be considered as off topic when there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834/recommended-web-development-environment-on-mac) for mac. Weird...

- Why should Mac be different than Win?
- Why should Python be considered a programming language rather than PHP?
- By the way, there is a bunch of web-development related tags... so are all those questions off-topic?
- If my question is so off-topic how come one user fav'ed it and another voted up?

If the moderators think my question is off-topic then delete it! I just don't get why **downvote** it. I don't mess around with other users' reputation, why should they mess with mine?

Call me "pretentious" but I **liked** to see my "100% accept rate". I also love every reputation point honestly gained helping others.

---

[UPDATE:] Thanks now I get why my question got closed. As for the downvotes, it's like you say "downvotes happen". Indeed, after this post I got another 2 downvotes... thanks, I guess.

Comment: As for the downvotes, don't worry too much. They happen to each and every one of us. Even if it's not deserved. Downvotes happen. :S

Comment: Just a side not, only questions that can have answers accepted count towards that number; thus questions with no answers for instance don't count

Comment: If you cry over lost rep, you're going to have a bad time. It's imaginary points on a website, don't worry about it.

Comment: @meagar: And if you ask enough questions with mostly downvotes, you get question-banned... *Then* people cry over lost access to said website.

Comment: @Martijn There's a difference between crying over *a downvote* and spamming us with terrible quality content. If you get question banned, you almost certainly deserve it.

Comment: @meagar: I quite agree, but to the question asker, the lost rep was a fair indicator that things weren't going to go their way. So downvotes on questions sometimes do matter.

Comment: Since one of the answers says dreamweaver can be configured to save to FTP, maybe you can rewrite the question to ask how to do that?

Comment: I'd say downvotes work best towards users who actually get upset about such downvotes: how much stronger can the community indicate that a question is unwanted? Sure, the other members could just vote to close, but it seems to me that especially the downvotes ensure the message is understood? I mean, if you care about your reputation you'll think twice now, when considering posting something new?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A couple things. First, I feel your pain. Nobody likes their questions closed. Sorry. Please don't take it personally! Nobody is out to get you -- this is just about what questions fit on StackOverflow, and which don't.

Second, "moderators" don't do this; SO is peer-moderated. Ordinary users voted your question as off-topic and closed it. After a question is closed, then people can, indeed, vote to delete it if there's something profoundly bad about it; that's not really the case here. You can actually edit a closed question and people can then vote to reopen it. If a question can be recast as a coding question, then this would apply; don't really think it's possible here.

Third, I think the question *is* off topic: questions are expected to pose a solveable programming problem. "Shopping" questions, or advice about choosing tools and libraries, are generally voted off topic. One reason is  that there's no one right answer to these; another reason is that they get stale faster than other kinds of answers. They're just not the kind of questions we want the site to consist of.

Finally, the Mac version is just as off-topic as yours, but it's four years old; the site has actually changed over time, and what was once considered on-topic no longer is.

Answer (score 15):

Stack Overflow's criteria have changed over time, and the other question (now 3 years old!) you point to would now also be considered off-topic.

In fact, it has now been closed as non-constructive after your post here drew attention to it.

Comment: I'd flag that NC (in fact I did), rather than OT myself.

Comment: @Gaffi: I already had done that exact same thing. :-)

Comment: Well I'm happy that my post had some useful purpose :) btw, thx for your editing on my post